# where is the error in the second IF statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, is-empty

i have VBA code that check entered dates with the current date and fill the cell in the appropriate color and check if the colomn **"F"** is not empty it will color the **D,E,F** columns.

the problem is that i have until now 21 records but the system just color  19 record even so the 2 rows are not empty in the F column.

## code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long

For i = Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'Range upto 5000, chnge this as per your requirment'

    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then
         Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = xlNone

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) < 0 Then
             Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) = 0 Then
             Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) >= 1 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) <= 4 Then
              Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) >= 5 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) <= 10 Then
               Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbCyan

    Else
                Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

 End If

    ' your 2nd criteria to color the entire row if "F" is not empty
    If Trim(Range("F" & i).Value) <> "" Then Range("D" & i & ":F" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15



Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why using VBA for that ? Looks like a job for `Conditional formatting`.

Comment: yes i know but i want to do it using vba

Comment: Code looks ok. Use `debug.print len(Range("F" & i).Value)` to check if cells are empty

Answer (score 1):

The `ElseIf` statements will throw `Runtime Error 13` if the cells have a non-date value in them. This is caused by trying to convert a non-date value into a date `VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3))`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1    'Range upto 5000, chnge this as per your requirment'

            If IsDate(Cells(i, 3)) Then
                Select Case VBA.CDate(.Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()
                    Case Is < 0
                        .Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                    Case Is = 0
                        .Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    Case Is <= 4
                        .Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed
                    Case Is <= 10
                        .Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbCyan
                    Case Else
                        .Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                End Select

            Else
                .Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End If

            ' your 2nd criteria to color the entire row if "F" is not empty
            If Trim(.Range("F" & i).Value) <> "" Then .Range("D" & i & ":F" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be something with your data, it runs properly to me. What kind of data do you have in the F column?

Comment: f column contains date